# how calculate bitwise and & between long and int in java?

Tags: java

iam working in project in java but i can not understand how compute the following statement:

```
 long input = 7851678454653875325L;
  char[] chars = new char[4];
  chars[0] = (char) ((input >>> 48) & 0xffff);
```

i want to know how calculate long type or convert it to binary first to `bitwise and &` operation .when debugging i notice that convert the hexadecimal value `0xffff` to int value then made the bitwise & operation.

Comment: I am confused you are saying int in question and statement shared uses __char__ and moreover, why do you need to convert long to binary to do bitwise, you can directly apply bitwise operations on long var

Comment: ok, how apply bitwise operation on long var without binary cconversion.@Aman Chhabra

Comment: By simply applying '&' operator. For example , jshell> long i = 10, k = 0; i = i&k;
results to 
k ==> 0
i ==> 0

Comment: Sorry, but this Question makes no sense to me.  There is no "binary conversion" necessary to do operations on integers.  They are already binary.  And as far as I can tell, what your code is (already) doing is exactly what is required.  (FWIW - the debugger is simply *displaying* the numbers as decimal, because that is your programmers normally want to see them.)  If I have misunderstood, then you need to edit the Question to make it clear what you want the code to actually do.

Comment: Looks like you want to extract a `char` from the top (i.e., high-order) 16 bits of a `long`, yes?